# How to access Cloud Firestore from a Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve data from my Cloud Firestore to eventually use in a GraphQL server, but for now I'm just returning JSON to test. I'm using the following code to access Firestore, but don't seem to be getting any data back. I know the function works correctly since the "start test" and "final test push" appears as expected in the JSON response.

I've tried using the Admin SDK instructions as well, to no avail. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
import * as functions from "firebase-functions"

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const db = admin.firestore()

const authors = [{ key: "start test" }]
db.collection("authors")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const data = {
                id: doc.id,
                firstName: doc.firstName,
                lastName: doc.lastName
            }
            authors.push(data)
            authors.push({ key: "test in loop" })
        })
    })
authors.push({ key: "final test push" })

export default authors
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I should note that this is from a separate getter file. The Cloud Function itself is elsewhere and is working properly.

EDIT #2: Cloud function definition

```
import authorsArray from "./firestore"

const testServer = express()
testServer.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ data: authorsArray }))
})
const test = https.onRequest(testServer)
```

Comment: I don't see a Cloud Function definition here.  You can't just push arbitrary code to Cloud Functions for execution - you have to declare a trigger of some sort that defines when the function should execute.

Comment: Is this the full content of you `index.js` file?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: this is a separate getter file. The Cloud Function proper is defined elsewhere and is working fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to change the code as follow; As snapshot data is `doc.data()` and id is `doc.id`

```
db.collection("authors")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const data = {
                id: doc.id,
                firstName: doc.data().firstName,
                lastName: doc.data().lastName
            }
            authors.push(data)
            authors.push({ key: "test in loop" })
        })
```

for your reference check the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)

Comment: Thank you! It's working now, but only on the second load after a hard refresh. The data from Firestore is also appearing after the "final test push". I'm guessing this is because of the asyncronous fetch?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)

Comment: How can I have it wait for the data before returning the response? I'm not sure where to add async/await, either in the getter file or the Cloud Function itself (added to the main post)

Comment: I think if you move up the final push one row up. It will wait foreach loop. Or you may check count nr with : `snapshot.forEach((doc, countnr) =>...`

Comment: Still the same problem, it takes a couple of refreshes before the Firestore data is included in the result.. :(

Comment: Then check foreach index nr.  As i try to explained.  At the loop below  check `if (countnr == snapshot.length -1) {authors.push({ key: "final test push" }) }` this must work.

Comment: I understand that will ensure that the final push will appear last, but it doesn't address the response not including the data the first time. Sorry if that wasn't clear..

Comment: Try to add  `return db.collection...` and inside the function `return authors` after final push.